# How do I use subprocess without sudo?

Tags: python

I have a script that executes its new command

```
openvpn_process = subprocess.Popen (['sudo', 'openvpn', '--config', 'tmp / tmp67fv65'])
```

How can I execute this same command without `sudo`?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server?

Comment: why are you omitting "-S" in de parameters? "-S' The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character."  and you do know about the sudoers file?